# Android layout and bring to top

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with layout. Look at the picture:
[image]

as you can see stars are over text and buttons. how I can do that text and buttons are over stars? This stars is animation. this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Czy chcesz kontynuować?/Do you want to continous?"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="158dp"
                android:text="Nie/No" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="94dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonNo"
                android:text="Tak/Yes" />

        </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView15"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView23"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView24"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView25"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView26"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView27"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView28"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView29"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView30"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView31"
          android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView32"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView33"
           android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView34"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView35"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView36"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView37"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView38"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView39"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView40"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView41"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView42"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView43"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView44"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView45"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView46"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView47"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView48"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView49"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView50"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView51"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView52"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView53"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView54"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView55"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                                <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView56"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView57"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                                    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView58"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView59"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />
                                                                                                                        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView60"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star_bez_nog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a layout file that consists of all the stars and an another layout that contains button and textview and what ever you want.
Now Create a layout frame layout that contains both the layout first add stars layout and then buttons layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you  want the stars to be on the bottom, put them in a RelativeLayout and put them at the top of your layout file. Your XML layout files work from top to bottom so everything written after will be put on top of that RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the programmers will probably skip reading your xml file. You really should learn how to use an Array or ArrayList to display star ImageViews (random) on the screen. Give the question text a background + border and viola! Mission solved!